# how to remove class hide with hover on each link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove class `hide` from div with class `popover` with hover on each link and my `popover` was shown but my code do not work correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myPopover").each(function() {
    var doc = $(this);
    doc.mouseover(function() {
      doc.find('.popover').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.popover {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.popover.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.popover.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="myPopover">help</a>
<div class="popover hide">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="myPopover">help2</a>
<div class="popover hide">
    <h4>title2</h4>
    <p>content2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add event-handler multiple-time.One-time is enough. Please check my answer for details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a non JS solution, which is better in the event that someone has JS disabled, you should only use JS when HTML & CSS can't really do something, something as simple as this can be easily accomplished with **JUST** HTML & CSS.

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.popover {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.popover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.myPopover:hover ~ .popover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="myPopover">help</a>
  <div class="popover hide">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="myPopover">help2</a>
  <div class="popover">
    <h4>title2</h4>
    <p>
      content2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through all elements with "myPopover" class try to bind an event handler to all of them at the same time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".myPopover").hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).next('.popover').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    }, function() {
      $( this ).next('.popover').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
  );

});
```

Additionally, depending on what version of jquery you're using you could use the built-in `$('.popover').hide()` and `$('.popover').show()` provided by jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
      $(".myPopover").hover(
        function() {
  $(this).next('.popover').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        }, function() {
 $(this).next('.popover').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
      );
    
});
```

```css
.popover {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.popover.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.popover.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="myPopover">help</a>
<div class="popover hide">
  <h4>title</h4>
  <p>
    content
  </p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="myPopover">help2</a>
<div class="popover hide">
  <h4>title2</h4>
  <p>
    content2
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
doc.next('.popover').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
```

find - finds the element inside it, but you have .popover next to the anchor tag.

Anyways, since you are using mouseover to remove class "hide" and add "show", your popup will just open not close, you nee handle it either by using hover function in and out to show and hide your popup, or have a close button to close the popup.

Thanks, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove the class "hide" from the div that follows a link when the link is hovered on. here's how that would work

```
$(".myPopover").hover(function(){ //when you hover on any link  with class myPopover this goes off
    var div = $(this).next(".popover"); //gets the next sibling element if it has the class popover
    $(div).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a different approach using de function `on` :

`$( document ).on('mouseover', '.myPopover', function(e){
     $( this ).next('.popover').removeClass ('hide');
});`

Also you can set ids to your elements, then you can easily find then no matters where it is positioned.